# Doppelte Negation - überflüssig, sinnentstellend?

Tags: negation

Ich zerbreche mir den Kopf über den untenstehenden Satz, der eine doppelte Negation enthält.

> „Der Doktorand verpflichtet sich, die beim XY allgemein geltenden Regelungen - soweit sie nicht ihrem Sinne nach für wissenschaftliche Hilfskräfte unanwendbar sind - insbesondere die Vorschriften über den Unfall- und Strahlenschutz, zu befolgen.“

Diesen Satz muß ich ins Englische übersetzen. Aus meiner Sicht ist das Adverb „nicht“ völlig überflüssig. Will man damit zum Ausdruck bringen, daß die Regelungen nicht unanwendbar sind, d.h. anwendbar für Hilfskräfte.

Welcher Unterschied ergäbe sich, wenn der Satz wie folgt umformuliert wäre:

> soweit sie ihrem Sinne nach für wissenschaftliche Hilfskräfte anwendbar sind

Anzumerken ist, daß dieser Text von einem Juristen verfasst wurde. Aus Erfahrung weiß ich, daß nicht alle Juristen mit den Subtilitäten der deutschen Sprache vertraut sind.

Ich wäre für jeden konstruktiven Hinweis (N.B. bitte um Verständnis, das ich privat die alte Rechtschreibung aus Überzeugung verwende).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Für mich als juristischen Laien scheint klar, dass eine Vorschrift, die *nicht unanwendbar* ist, *anwendbar* sein sollte, andernfalls gäbe es einen rechtlichen Orkus von Vorschriften, die weder anwendbar noch unanwendbar sind.

Es wäre sicherlich interessant, den verfassenden Juristen um einige Beispiele für Vorschriften zu bitten, die in der gegebenen Situation nicht unanwendbar, aber auch nicht anwendbar sind – erst deren Existenz würde seine Formulierung rechtfertigen.

Aber als Übersetzer würde ich in den sauren Apfel beißen und den Satz so lassen, wie er ist, denn es ist davon auszugehen, dass die Formulierung Absicht ist und der Autor sie auch in der Zielsprache so haben möchte.

Comment: vielen herzlichen Dank! Der Autor besteht auf die Richtigkeit des Satzes. Mir bleibt also nur noch der saure Apfel.

Comment: Ich wiederum als Übersetzer würde einen solchen Satz nicht wörtlich übersetzen sondern sinngemäß, denn Übersetzung sollte immer eine Übertragung des Sinns in eine andere Sprache sein, nicht etwa einer Wortfolge. Wobei ich dann natürlich genau vor Veroniques Frage stehe. Vielleicht ist aber auch die Unterscheidung von "x" und "nicht un-x" im juristischen Englischen nicht unähnlich. Das kann ich leider nicht nicht unbeantwortet lassen.

Answer (score 13):

Hier wird die doppelte Verneinung wirklich gebraucht.

> ... soweit sie ... unanwendbar sind

würde bedeuten, dass Vorschriften, die nicht anwendbar sind, anzuwenden sind, was natürlich Unsinn ist.

> ... soweit sie ... anwendbar sind

würde nicht ganz genau dasselbe bedeuten: Dort würde man erwarten, dass jeder, bevor er eine Vorschrift befolgt, erst mal drüber nachdenken soll, ob sie anwendbar sei. Dieser Satz soll, so wie er da steht, eben zum Ausdruck bringen, dass das Befolgen der Vorschrift der Normalfall sein soll und nur, wenn es gar nicht anders geht, ignoriert werden können.

Comment: Super, Herzlichen Dank für die prompte Antwort. Würden Sie anhand des folgenden Beispiels eine Analogie zu meinem Problemsatz bejahen: "Soweit Sie nicht pünktlich erscheinen, können wir Ihren Vortrag nicht übertragen" ?

Comment: Zweimal "nicht" ist immer schlechter, als wenn man "nicht" mit "un-" ersetzt. Diesen Satz würde ich formulieren als "Wenn Sie weiterhin so unpünktlich erscheinen sollten, können wir ihren Vortrag nicht übertragen"

Comment: Ich verstehe, Danke!

Comment: Du magst recht haben mit der theoretischen Unterscheidung von *anwendbar* und *nicht unanwendbar*. Jedoch aus Sicht des Doktoranden, um den es hier ja geht, ist das einerlei. Er kann den Satz ruhig lesen als *...soweit sie auch für Hilfskräfte gelten...*, und versteht trotzdem alles richtig. Oder vielleicht gerade dann.

Comment: Wo kam in dem Kommentar denn jetzt das *weiterhin so* her?

Comment: @CarstenS Es war plötzlich da.

Comment: ok, then.... ;)

Answer (score 6):

Formulierungen wie "nicht unanwendbar" werden in der Juristensprache standardmäßig verwendet, um klarzustellen, dass eine Ausnahme ("im Fall X unanwendbar") *nicht* vorliegt. Dies ist ein wenig präziser als ein "anwendbar sein", in das man theoretisch ein "kann, muss aber nicht" hineininterpretieren könnte.
Ob man bei der Übersetzung die doppelte Verneinung beibehält oder die umformulierte Version als Ausgangspunkt benutzt, dürfte wesentlich davon abhängen, ob es sich um einen erklärenden Text handelt, oder ob auch die übersetzte Version vertragsrechtliche Relevanz haben soll.

Comment: *Dies ist ein wenig präziser als ein "anwendbar sein", in das man theoretisch ein "kann, muss aber nicht" hineininterpretieren könnte.* Genau  darum geht es: sollen wir, dürfen wir, können, wir müssen wir? Wenn wir können und dürfen, dann müssen wir!

Answer (score 2):

Ähnliche Beispiele finden sich bspw. im Strafgesetzbuch. Nachdem eine explizite Erklärung in den gängigen StGB-Kommentaren nicht zu finden war, lautet meine Schlussfolgerung:

Es könnte sich um eine Umkehr der Beweislast handeln. Denn wäre die Formulierung positiv, wäre es klar Teil des Tatbestandes. Andersherum ist es explizit kein Tatbestandsmerkmal.

Bin kein Jurist. Eine offizielle, authoritäre Antwort aus Rechtsprechung und Schrifttum würde mich wohl auch interessieren.

Answer (score 0):

Eine Vorschrift muss befolgt werden, es sei denn, sie ist für die Personengruppe nicht anwendbar.
Die erste Umformulierung würde bedeuten, der Doktorand müsste selbst für wissenschaftliche Hilfskräfte unanwendbare Vorschriften befolgen. Also genau das Gegenteil.

Answer (score 0):

Wie wärs mit:

> soweit sie ihrem Sinne nach für wissenschaftliche Hilfskräfte nicht unanwendbar sind ... ?

Vielleicht würde uns auf die Sprünge helfen, wenn wir versuchten uns vorzustellen, was hiermit gemeint sein könnte:

> insbesondere die Vorschriften über den Unfall- und Strahlenschutz, zu befolgen.“

Hilfskräfte verfügen nicht unbedingt über alle nötigen Ausrüstungen (Schutzanzüge), Fachwissen und Kenntnisse, Handlungskompetenzen, etc, die möglicherweise bei einem Unfall mit Radioaktivität anzuwenden wären.

Sind die Regelungen z. B. aufgrund fehlender Kompetenzen vom Hilfspersonal nicht anwendbar, können sie von diesem auch nicht befolgt werden.

Andernfalls gelten sie für alle, auch für das Hilfspersonal. Es gäbe dann keinen Grund, dass sie  unanwendbar wären. (Das ist mit  „soweit sie nicht“ gemeint!)

Es geht also hier um die Absicherung von Kompetenzen und Verantwortung bei einem Störfall, so dass sich niemand herausreden kann, man hätte „es” nicht gewusst.

Es ist in dieser Hinsicht keine doppelte Verneinung: Das „nicht“ bezieht sich nicht auf unanwendbar sondern auf: „insofern sie nicht“ ...

Comment: Die Ausführung zu der Beispielhaften Anwendung irritiert mich etwas, denn ich hatte etwas anderes vermutet, und würde behaupten, dass fehlende Kompetenzen das Hilfspersonal direkt ausschließen. So oder so lenkt es vom letzten Teil ab, der die eigentliche Antwort enthält, bei der hier weitgehend Einigkeit besteht.